# Adding records to a drop down menu without form refresh

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to add records to a drop down menu without form refresh. I'm using codeigniter and bootstrap

Here is the Bootstrap Modal :

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
            <h4 id="myLargeModalLabel" class="modal-title">Add Record</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <form class="sky-form" id="sky-inchidere" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="">
                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

                        <dt>Name<span class="color-red">*</span></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <section>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-inbox"></i>
                                    <input type="text" value="" name="name" required>
                                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Add New Record</b>
                                </label>
                            </section>
                        </dd>

                    </dl>
                <hr>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-u" style="float:right; margin-top:-5px;">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#sky-inchidere").submit(function(e){     
    e.preventDefault();
    var tdata= $("#sky-inchidere").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/new/oportunitati/add',
        data: tdata, 

        success:function(tdata)
        {
            alert('SUCCESS!!');
        },
        error: function (XHR, status, response) {
           alert('fail');
        }
    });
});
});
```

CI Controller ( i have added the modal code here for test )

```
public function add()   {
    $tdata = array( name=>  $this->input->post(name),
                   );
    $this->db->insert('table',$tdata); 
}
```

When i use this code i get "fail" error message.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

how yo debug:
1. Print your 'tdata' and see what happen;
2. Something wrong here: $this->input->post('name');

Comment: tried to print 'tdata' in console and see what is in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$tdata = array( 
    'name' =>  $this->input->post('name')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find the problem and correct it. (typo on the table name)
Now I have come across a different problem. In the ajax success I cant refresh the chosen dropdown records i have tried :

```
       success:function(tdata)
       {
           // close the modal
           $('#myModal').modal('hide');

           // update dropdown ??
           $('.chosen-select').trigger('liszt:updated');
           $('#field-beneficiar_p').trigger('chosen:updated');
           $('#field-beneficiar_p').trigger('liszt:updated');
       },
```

Any help in how i can refresh the records to see the last added item will be appreciated.  I'm using chosen plugin.

Answer (score 0):

from controller send data in `json_encode`
then in js function

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('login/get_time'); ?>",
                    data: {"consltant_name": consltant_name, "time": time},
                    success: function(data) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(data);
                        var options = '';
                        options = options + '<option value="">Please Select One</option>'
                        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                            options = options + '<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>'
                        });
                        selectbox.html(options);
                    }});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand how to modify my code to fix my problem .. Is there any way to provide a more detailed example ?